# I am receiving a reference error in AWS lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am trying to learn to make a web app and I am trying to follow the tutorial provided by AWS but I am coming in to this issue in making a Lambda function.

```
{
  "errorType": "ReferenceError",
  "errorMessage": "exports is not defined in ES module scope",
  "trace": [
    "ReferenceError: exports is not defined in ES module scope",
    "    at file:///var/task/index.mjs:3:1",
    "    at ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:193:25)",
    "    at async Promise.all (index 0)",
    "    at async ESMLoader.import (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:530:24)",
    "    at async _tryAwaitImport (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:921:16)",
    "    at async _tryRequire (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:970:86)",
    "    at async _loadUserApp (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:994:16)",
    "    at async UserFunction.js.module.exports.load (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1035:21)",
    "    at async start (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1200:23)",
    "    at async file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1206:1"
  ]
}
```

index.mjs

```
// Define handler function, the entry point to our code for the Lambda service

// We receive the object that triggers the function as a parameter
exports.handler = async (event) => {
    // Extract values from event and format as strings
    let name = JSON.stringify(`Hello from Lambda, ${event.firstName} ${event.lastName}`);
    // Create a JSON object with our response and store it in a constant
    const response = {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: name
    };
    // Return the response constant
    return response;
};
```

JSON
{
"firstName":"Tyler",
"lastName":"Schnitzer"
}

It is suppose to be a simple hello world but I am confused why I can't get the event to work?

I am hoping someone can help explain this error and how to solve it, I tried looking through AWS Lambda trouble shooting page, but I still don't understand.

Comment: Which tutorial? Does your package.json indicate `"type": "module"`?

Comment: Also, see [Using Node.js ES modules and top-level await in AWS Lambda](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/using-node-js-es-modules-and-top-level-await-in-aws-lambda/) given that you appear to be using ES modules.

Answer (score 3):

Solved this same problem by changing:

```
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
```

for

```
export const handler = (event, context, callback)  => {
```

Found this solution in this [AWS Forum](https://repost.aws/questions/QUEcvqsCYHT7CP6gEyzsPd7g/aws-lambda-es6-module-error-module-is-not-defined-in-es-module-scope).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error. I deleted and recreated the lambda function with a runtime of Node.js 14.x, it works fine. The error was with Node.js 18.x, which is the default as of this writing.
I was following this tutorial, https://www.eventbox.dev/published/lesson/innovator-island/2-realtime/2-backend.html